# How to send ajax response like download button to download files Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to display download link button on my view (if my ajax is success)
follwings is my download  code to send ajax response and dispaly on view

```
<div class="blog-moder-button">
  <a  href="public_path('files').'/'.$request->file_name" class="button-md dark-button downlds">
    Download PDF
  </a>
</div>
```

following is my controller

```
public function 

downloadform(Request $request) {        
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'file_name' => 'required',
     ]
  );

  if ($validator->passes()) {
    $msg= array();
    // $msg['success'] = '<div class="alert alert-success"> Successfully Registered</div>';//it is working 
    $msg['success'] = '<div class="blog-moder-button"> <a  href="public_path('files').'/'.$request->file_name"  class="button-md dark-button downlds"> Download PDF</a></div>';//it is not working
  }

  return response()->json($msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not render html inside your controller, that is the job of your view.

To trigger a file download response use this:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#file-downloads